# Program Guidance - DO WHILE loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, while-loop

I need some structural help! I know how to get what I need done but I can't decipher how to do it via a loop.

So I have a database of IDs in a text file. They are separated by lines for ease of reading. I need to read the ID, download a file based on that ID and date for a date range. I understand how to read the line using streamreader and can do that just fine for 1 file using 1 ID and date, I have that code working fine.

I was think of using a Do While loop but quickly realized that I can download each date for a single ID, I can't loop back to go to the next ID and do the same (or maybe I can and I just don't know how yet)...

The download is based on DateTimePicker2 value. So basically this needs to download the file from ftp://ftp.address.net/UserID/yyyyMMdd.txt.

Sorry to take back a solution but this code reads line 1, attempts to download the file and then stops.

```
For Each strUserID As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("database.txt")
Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value 
Do While myDate < DateTimePicker3.Value
    Dim ftpAddr As String = "ftp://ftp.address.net/" & strUserID & myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
    Dim myPath As String = "MyFolder'" & strUserID & myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt" 'or whatever the path should be
    Try
        My.Computer.Network.Download(ftpAddr, myPath)
    Catch nullDownload as IO.IOException
    Continue For
    End Try

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.Exists(myPath)
        For Each line as String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myPath)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
            Next
        End If                  

        myDate.AddDays(1)
    Loop
Next
```

I basically need to loop the loop again using the next line in the database.txt.

Edit: Quick summary of what I'm trying to do:

1. Read the ID starting from line 1 in the database.txt
     1a. Download the file based on DateTimePicker2 value (ftp://ftp.address.net/userID/yyyyMMdd.txt)
     1b. Write it to the DataGridView
     1c. Add 1 to the date and repeat from step 1a, repeating until  DateTimePicker2 > DateTimePicker3
2. Read the next ID in the database.txt and loop steps 1a-1c but from the initial chosen date.

Comment: Not an answer but still valuable points of advice IMHO: first, this loop will never start because your initial condition will always be `False`. Second, you should not mix application logic with user interface. And third, hiding every possible exception is a practice you should seriously question.

Comment: You shouldn't use date picker like this. Put the value in a variable and use that variable. At the end of your loop, DateTimePicker2 will be equal to DateTimePicker3. Also, in your case, strUserID will always be empty.

Comment: @crono i was intending on catching the downloads that do not exist as exceptions. i just need to skip them and I don't know of another way to do that. any tips are appreciated, this is my first real project!

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops. An outer loop to process each UserID, and an inner loop the process all dates with that UserID.

If each UserID is a separate line in the text file, you can use `File.ReadAllLines` to read them into an array and use a `For Each` loop to process each UserID. Then make sure that each time you pick a new UserID, you set the date back to the initial date.

```
For Each strUserID As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("database.txt")
    Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value 
    Do While myDate < DateTimePicker3.Value
        Dim ftpAddr As String = "ftp://ftp.address.net/" & strUserID & myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
        Dim myPath As String = "MyFolder'" & strUserID & myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt" 'or whatever the path should be
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.Download(ftpAddr, myPath)
        Catch nullDownload as exception
        End Try

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.Exists(myPath)
            For Each line as String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myPath)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
            Next
        End If                  

        myDate.AddDays(1)
    Loop
Next
```

[Edit]
I have edited to code to match the edited version of the question. The name of the file to be downloaded is based on the UserID and the date.

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't get past the first ID. i need a way to proceed in the event the file doesn't exist when attempting to download, thats where my exception was listed above. thank you for this block of code, it sounds like its in the right direction of what i need.

Comment: @VashTS isn't the code that skips files that don't exist already in your code for downloading and processing the file (that I replaced with a comment)? I'll add your code back in case that is confusing you.

Comment: thats why the Try Catch is in there (potentially). maybe i'm not implementing the Try properly?? my idea was to try downloading the file, if its not there catch as an exception, but still proceed. but still this only attempts to download the first ID, fails and loops back to the first ID.

Comment: @VashTS perhaps the problem is in code that you haven't shown us (I assume you posted a simplified version). The code in you post only ever downloads the same file, and never does anything with the UserId or date.

Comment: I changed it over to the exact code you just posted. I think I might have missed an important detail when asking this question...the file to download is actually based on the date - its yyyyMMdd.txt. i'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: @VashTS I have updated my answer to match your changes. Does that help?

Comment: i copied it line for line, but still only downloads the first ID. i think the problem is that the first ID doesn't have a file and I need to find a way around that.

Comment: its definitely the problem...removing the Try Catch causes an IO Exception because the file doesn't exist. so i bet your code works, I just need a way around that :)